# Errors to do with modules when using net-snmp utils

Tags: linux, snmp

I was using the net-snmp packages that come with my linux distro (version 5.3.2.2), but wanted to do some work with the latest version of net-snmp (5.7), so tried compiling and installing the new source. It seemed to work ok but now I'm getting a load of errors when use net-snmp utils (snmpget, snmpset snmpwalk etc..)

for example:

```
$ snmptranslate -On SNMPv2-MIB::system.sysDescr
MIB search path: /home/me/.snmp/mibs:/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI) At line 6 in /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 9 in /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 9 in (none)
:
<a lot of similar lines>
:
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 9 in (none)
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1
```

From this I assumed perhaps that I was missing mibs from the 'MIB search path', so I looked at the first error 'Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI)', however it seems to be in the right directory:

```
$ ls /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/*SNMPv2-SMI*
/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.txt
```

And the same result for the other in the list.. so I'm wondering if anybody knows why it might not be finding the modules even though they seem to be in the search path?

Comment: Looks like the solution to your problem is in [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/net-snmp-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg28230.html) thread.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the 5.7 release that can cause this error message to be shown when it shouldn't be.  Try using the 5.7.1.rc3 release (or wait a week until the final 5.7.1 comes out).

Answer (score 0):

As anotha office gangsta eluded to, this issue might be due to a bug in 5.7 release.. nevathaless.. the issue you're encountering with the Net-SNMP utilities can be caused by several factors. Let's dig in..

**1. Check MIB Search Path:**

Verify that the MIB search path you specified is correct. Use the net-snmp-config command to check the configured MIB directories:

```
net-snmp-config --default-mibdirs
```

Ensure that the path /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs is included in the MIB search path.

**2. MIB Directory Ownership and Permissions:**

Ensure that the MIB files in the directory /usr/local/share/snmp/mibs have the correct ownership and permissions. They should be readable by the user running the snmp* utilities.

**3. Recompile MIBs:**

After installing a new version of Net-SNMP, it's a good practice to recompile the MIB files to ensure they are compatible with the new version. You can do this by running:

```
sudo net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -A authpass -X privpass -a MD5 -x DES myuser
```

Replace **authpass** and **privpass** with your desired authentication and privacy passphrases, and **myuser** with the desired username. This command generates necessary configuration files and MIBs.

**4. Check MIB Names and Filenames:**

Verify that the MIB names you are using in your commands are correct and match the filenames in the MIB directory. MIB names are case-sensitive, so make sure they match exactly.

**5. MIB Compilation Errors:**

Check if there were any errors during the compilation and installation of Net-SNMP. Review the output of the ./configure, make, and make install commands for any error messages related to MIBs.

**6. MIB Loading Configuration:**

Ensure that the Net-SNMP configuration file (snmp.conf) is correctly configured to load MIBs. This file is usually located in /etc/snmp/ or /usr/local/share/snmp/. Check if it includes the following line:

```
mibs +ALL
```

The +ALL option tells Net-SNMP to load all available MIBs. Make sure this line is uncommented (remove the # if present).

**7. Environment Variables:**

Check if any environment variables related to Net-SNMP are set. These variables, such as MIBS, can affect MIB loading behavior. Ensure that there are no conflicting environment variables that override your MIB search path.

**8. Cache Issues:**

If you have previously used an older version of Net-SNMP, there might be cached MIB information. Try clearing the cache by removing any files in **/var/net-snmp** or **/var/net-snmp/snmpapp.conf** and then retesting.

After checkedity-checkin these steps, try running dem Net-SNMP utilities again. If the issue persists, you might want to load up a new question with more details and whatnot about the specific commands and configs you're using so that I can dig in deeper my dude.

Peace!!